# Make zsh show autocomplete choices even when a possible match is entered

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

On my current system (openSUSE 12.3 with zsh 5.0.2) the autocomplete function does not give me a choice of possible completions if I have already entered a possible completion match.

For example, if I am in a directory with two files named *file* and *file2* and I type:

```
cat file<TAB>
```

Then a space will be appended, and I will have no indication that *file2* was also a possible match. Is it possible to change this behaviour? Bash behaves better in this case (it will show both *file* and *file2* without adding a space), but any solution that does not hide possible matches would also be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zstyle ':completion:*' accept-exact false`

from `zshcompsys(1)`

```
accept-exact
              This  is  tested for the default tag in addition to the tags valid for the current context.  If it is set to `true' and any of the trial matches is the
              same as the string on the command line, this match will immediately be accepted (even if it would otherwise be considered ambiguous).
```

You can also make the zstyle's context more specific instead of it affecting every type of completion.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, because I also have zsh 5.0.2 on openSUSE 12.3, and my zsh behaves exactly the way you want.  Unfortunately I can't remember which setting in my `.zshrc` does the trick, but you can [look at it yourself](https://github.com/aspiers/shell-env/blob/master/.zshrc) and hopefully you will be able to figure it out.  I'm guess it's either one of the `setopt` options, or one of the `zstyle` lines, but it's years since I wrote most of those ...